# Can I reuse built-in IIS authentication but provide my own credentials checking?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, security, iis

I'd like to use built-in IIS authentication with non-Windows accounts. There's [this module that does that for basic authentication](http://custombasicauth.codeplex.com/), but it in fact does both the authentication and credentials checking.

The problem is I also need to support digest authentication and I could try to do it, but it would be a lot of hassle - I need to generate challenges ("nonces") securely, store them and check for replays, etc. - lots of things I can screw up and make determined attackers happy.

So I'd prefer to reuse the digest authentication functionality in IIS, but use my own module for credentials validation. How can I do that?

Comment: Credentials checking *is* authentication. Do you mean working out whether the user is allowed in? This is *authorization*.

Comment: @Roger Lipscombe: Well, maybe. I want my own credentials validation only.

Comment: Authentication is "You say you're *sharptooth*. Prove it.";  Authorization is "Assuming that you are *sharptooth*, here's what you're allowed to do."

Comment: @Roger Lipscombe: I want IIS to do the first part via digest authentication and my code will do the second part.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no existing solution. To use IIS built-in Digest authentication, you have to choose "Form", which is not what you want.

One possible solution is to use anonymous authentication in IIS, and write an http module to handle both authentication and authorization.

There are some existing code at codeproject, where you may want to check out.

Answer (score 0):

You might try something called "ASP.NET Membership".
The only drawback is you have to use "Forms Authentication".

The basic concept is here

- [MSDN: Introduction to Membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx)

You can even write a "Custom Membership Provider" if you don't want to use one of ASP.NET's default providers (e.g. SQL Server)

- [MSDN: Implementing a Membership Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e.aspx)